# PHP Get image from whatsapp with curl

Tags: php, curl, whatsapp, imagedownload

To download an image received from the webhook, first, i retrieve the url with the call to the media endpoint, I execute a curl call to

https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/790316572396xxx

where 790316572396xxx is the media id.

The code i uso to do that is:

```
$token = 'EAAUqqMYzU ... WDRogwDtLZCh';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/790316572396xxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));
 
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response."<hr>";

$dati = json_decode($response);
```

and te $response is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [url] => https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=790316572396xxx&ext=1659596318&hash=ATuHn61BbJOBYzugyRcP6O6UnyY2NSVh3Bb8v12OS3OCzQ
    [mime_type] => image/jpeg
    [sha256] => 1cf4a54f0d86c6603d10ad2e9836bc5a98edfabab4b5b8120822be59cbdcxxx0
    [file_size] => 253685
    [id] => 790316572396xxx
    [messaging_product] => whatsapp
)
```

after this, i make a new curl call to the obtained **URL**

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $dati->url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
    
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

$getstatusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($getstatusCode == 200){
    
    echo 'Downloaded!<hr>';
        
    echo $response;
    
} else{
    
    echo "Status Code: " . $getstatusCode;
    
}
```

But the $response obtained is the "something went wrong"

[screenshot of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n82r1.png)

I would have expected a binary blob instead.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks to anyone who wants to give me an answer!

Comment: try open url in browser first, make sure url working

Comment: Trying to open the url, directly in the browser, you get the same answer, but in this case it is understandable, because the header with the app token is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with me,
Just you have to send *Media URL* that you got from this route response

> https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/790316572396xxx

and send *Media Url* and *full file name with the extension **example** "whatsapp-image.jpg"*

```
public globalFileHandle;

public function saveMediaContent($url, $filename)
{
    try {
        $config    = config('services.whatsapp');
        $userAgent = $this->generateUserAgent();

        // -----------------------
        set_time_limit(0);

        # Open the file for writing...
        $this->globalFileHandle = fopen(public_path($filename), 'w+');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //Make this valid if possible
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); # optional
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, -1); # optional: -1 = unlimited, 3600 = 1 hour
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false); # Set to true to see all the innards

        # Only if you need to bypass SSL certificate validation
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        # Assign a callback function to the CURL Write-Function
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'curlWriteFile');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $this->globalFileHandle);

        # Assign Headers
        $headers = [];
        $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer {$config['token']}";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        # Exceute the download - note we DO NOT put the result into a variable!
        curl_exec($ch);

        // Check if any error occurred
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            return false;
        }

        # Close CURL
        curl_close($ch);

        # Close the file pointer
        fclose($this->globalFileHandle);

        return true;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return false;
    }
}

public function curlWriteFile($cp, $data) {
    $len = fwrite($this->globalFileHandle, $data);
    return $len;
}

/**
 * Get Dynamic User-Agent
 *
 * @param [type] $userAgent
 * @return void
 */
public function generateUserAgent($userAgent = NULL) {
    if($userAgent === NULL) {
        $r = random_int(0, 100);
        if($r >= 44) {
            $userAgent = array_rand([ 'firefox' => 1, 'chrome' => 1, 'explorer' => 1 ]);
        } else {
            $userAgent = array_rand([ 'iphone' => 1, 'android' => 1, 'mobile' => 1 ]);
        }
    } elseif($userAgent == 'windows' || $userAgent == 'mac' || $userAgent == 'linux') {
        $agents = [ 'firefox' => 1, 'chrome' => 1 ];
        if($userAgent == 'windows') {
            $agents['explorer'] = 1;
        }
        $userAgent = array_rand($agents);
    }
    $_SESSION['agent'] = $userAgent;
    if($userAgent == 'chrome') {
        return 'Mozilla/5.0 (' . $this->getOS($userAgent) . ') AppleWebKit/' . (random_int(1, 100) > 50 ? random_int(533, 537) : random_int(600, 603)) . '.' . random_int(1, 50) . ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/' . self::chromeVersion([ 'min' => 47,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          'max' => 55 ]) . ' Safari/' . (random_int(1, 100) > 50 ? random_int(533, 537) : random_int(600, 603));
    } elseif($userAgent == 'firefox') {

        return 'Mozilla/5.0 (' . $this->getOS($userAgent) . ') Gecko/' . (random_int(1, 100) > 30 ? '20100101' : '20130401') . ' Firefox/' . self::firefoxVersion([ 'min' => 45,
                                                                                                                                                                    'max' => 74 ]);
    } elseif($userAgent == 'explorer') {

        return 'Mozilla / 5.0 (compatible; MSIE ' . ($int = random_int(7, 11)) . '.0; ' . $this->getOS('windows') . ' Trident / ' . ($int == 7 || $int == 8 ? '4' : ($int == 9 ? '5' : ($int == 10 ? '6' : '7'))) . '.0)';
    } elseif($userAgent == 'mobile' || $userAgent == 'android' || $userAgent == 'iphone' || $userAgent == 'ipad' || $userAgent == 'ipod') {

        return 'Mozilla/5.0 (' . $this->getMobileOS($userAgent) . ') AppleWebKit/' . (random_int(1, 100) > 50 ? random_int(533, 537) : random_int(600, 603)) . '.' . random_int(1, 50) . ' (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/' . self::chromeVersion([ 'min' => 47,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 'max' => 55 ]) . ' Mobile Safari/' . (random_int(1, 100) > 50 ? random_int(533, 537) : random_int(600, 603)) . '.' . random_int(0, 9);
    } else {
        new \Exception('Unable to determine user agent to generate');
    }
}
```